# In a distributed system, does the Coordinator communicate with all Participants at the same time or tell one of them, who has to inform the others?

Tags: communication, distributed-system

I'm reading up on the communication in a distributed system but just can't find an answer to that specific questions. All the diagrams I'm given are vague about it.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinator communicates with all other participants. This is a common design paradigm for distributed sequencing like a distributed chat system.

The leader is usually elected by a consensus algorithm